# Java Remote Desktop(not working with Internet)

Tags: java

My application has a server & client,these 2 r connected through socket.Now the server will

control the desktop of client..client will capture the screens (by awt.Robot) and send it to

the server when ever an event occurs(mouse event or key event)..This is working fine & I am

able to get the screen shots within no time through LAN & WAN.But when I am connecting the

server & client through Internet,the transfer a screen shots getting delayed,if an event

happens then the updated screen will come after 2 mins..I am storing the screen capture to

BufferedImage & converting it to ImageIcon since it's serializable,&  writing it to

ObjectOutputStream so that Server will catch the image through ObjectInputStream..

So How can I increase the speed of my app through Internet,I am not concerned about the

image quality..I just need fast transfer...

This is for Client...

```
    import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

/**
 * This class is responisble for sending sreenshot every predefined duration
 */
class ScreenSpyer extends Thread {

    Socket socket = null; 
    Robot robot = null; // Used to capture screen
    Rectangle rectangle = null; //Used to represent screen dimensions
    boolean continueLoop = true; //Used to exit the program

    public ScreenSpyer(Socket socket, Robot robot,Rectangle rect) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.robot = robot;
        rectangle = rect;
        start();
    }

    public void run(){
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null; //Used to write an object to the streem


        try{
            //Prepare ObjectOutputStream
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            /*
             * Send screen size to the server in order to calculate correct mouse
             * location on the server's panel
             */
            oos.writeObject(rectangle);
        }catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

       while(continueLoop){
            //Capture screen
            BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
            /* I have to wrap BufferedImage with ImageIcon because BufferedImage class
             * does not implement Serializable interface
             */
            ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(image);

            //Send captured screen to the server
            try {
                System.out.println("before sending image");

                oos.writeObject(imageIcon);
                oos.reset(); //Clear ObjectOutputStream cache
                System.out.println("New screenshot sent");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            //wait for 100ms to reduce network traffic
            try{
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

This is for Server

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 * @author Halim
 * ClientScreenReciever is responsible for recieving client screenshot and displaying
 * it in the server. Each connected client has a separate object of this class
 */
class ClientScreenReciever extends Thread {

    private ObjectInputStream cObjectInputStream = null;
    private JPanel cPanel = null;
    private boolean continueLoop = true;

    public ClientScreenReciever(ObjectInputStream ois, JPanel p) {
        cObjectInputStream = ois;
        cPanel = p;
        //start the thread and thus call the run method
        start();
    }

    public void run(){

            try {

                //Read screenshots of the client then draw them
                while(continueLoop){
                    //Recieve client screenshot and resize it to the current panel size
                    ImageIcon imageIcon = (ImageIcon) cObjectInputStream.readObject();
                    System.out.println("New image recieved");
                    Image image = imageIcon.getImage();
                    image = image.getScaledInstance(cPanel.getWidth(),cPanel.getHeight()
                                                        ,Image.SCALE_FAST);
                    //Draw the recieved screenshot
                    Graphics graphics = cPanel.getGraphics();
                    graphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, cPanel.getWidth(),cPanel.getHeight(),cPanel);
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
          } catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
              ex.printStackTrace();
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To the right when you were asking your question there was this handy **How to Format** box. Worth a read, as is [the page linked](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) from the **[?]** just above the question area.

Answer (score 0):

Zipping will not be enough to give a good user experience, as screen images normally do not zip that well.

You will need to do actual movie encoding to get a reasonable framerate.  I do not know any good movie encoder/decoder system running in Java.

Comment: Is there any library in java which can be used to compare two images (say for screenshots of desktop) and find out the only the locations which has changed..

Comment: Probably, but not one I know of.  You may want to investigate Ingo's answer more closely.

Answer (score 0):

Better yet, devise a scheme to transfer only the parts of the screen that have actually changed. This will make it speedier in the end and will not waste bandwith for unchanged screens. WIth modern display resolutions you'll have a hard time transferring entire screens.

Comment: Hmmm,I've been searching on that issue for transferring only the changed parts of the screen,but I didn't find any resource..Do u know one ??

Comment: What do you mean by "ressource"? You already are able to transmit whole screens, as far as I understand. So you know how to make a screen shot, or whatever you call it. So just remember the last state of the screen, and if anything changes, figure out the portion of the screen where it happened. Operators like ==, != or even ^ will be helpful here.

Comment: Still I didn't find anything useful,Do u know some links regarding dat which u think is helpful.

Comment: @user702076 - We all here love to help, but we're not here to free you from thnking, googling, etc. You should at least be able to formulate a concrete question, or describe where you're stuck.

Comment: Ahh, you have a BufferedImage. That's great. So what prevents you, for example, from using the methods getRGB on the one side and setRGB on the other?